# Vue.js - Element UI - Input remote search debounce

Tags: vuejs2

I'm using `vue.js 2.3` and `element-ui` `input remote search` component.
[documentation here](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/input)

I would like to be able to `debounce` using `lodash` the remote search, but I find it tricky because of the `cb` in `querySearchAsync(queryString, cb)`

https://jsfiddle.net/1tgqn7o8/

```
<div id="app">
Fetch suggestion counter : {{counter}}
<el-autocomplete v-model="state4" :fetch-suggestions="querySearchAsync" placeholder="Please input" @select="handleSelect"></el-autocomplete>
</div>

var Main = {
    data() {
      return {
        links: [],
        state4: '',
        timeout:  null,
        counter: 0,
      };
    },
    methods: {
      loadAll() {
        return [
          { "value": "vue", "link": "https://github.com/vuejs/vue" },
          { "value": "element", "link": "https://github.com/ElemeFE/element" },
          { "value": "cooking", "link": "https://github.com/ElemeFE/cooking" },
          { "value": "mint-ui", "link": "https://github.com/ElemeFE/mint-ui" },
          { "value": "vuex", "link": "https://github.com/vuejs/vuex" },
          { "value": "vue-router", "link": "https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router" },
          { "value": "babel", "link": "https://github.com/babel/babel" }
         ];
      },
      querySearchAsync(queryString, cb) {
        this.counter ++;
        var links = this.links;
        var results = queryString ? links.filter(this.createFilter(queryString)) : links;

        clearTimeout(this.timeout);
        this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          cb(results);
        }, 3000 * Math.random());
      },
      createFilter(queryString) {
        return (link) => {
          return (link.value.indexOf(queryString.toLowerCase()) === 0);
        };
      },
      handleSelect(item) {
        console.log(item);
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.links = this.loadAll();
    }
  };
var Ctor = Vue.extend(Main)
new Ctor().$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap the function the debounce.

```
querySearchAsync: _.debounce(function (queryString, cb) {
    this.counter ++;
    var links = this.links;
    var results = queryString ? links.filter(this.createFilter(queryString)) : links;

    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      cb(results);
    }, 3000 * Math.random());
  }, 500),
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tgqn7o8/1/).

Answer (score 7):

You can simply add the `debounce` atttribute like this:

```
<el-autocomplete :debounce="500" :fetch-suggestions="querySearchAsync" />
```

[See official documentation](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/input#autocomplete-attributes)

Cheers!